# How to Pass an Expression<Func<T1, T2>> to Create an Expression Tree with Other Values for use in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, expression, expression-trees

It's a bit hard to explain this one, so the easiest is by way of example.

I've been trying to execute a Func within a Func but it's not supported by Linq to Entities.

So first, what works...

```
internal class CategoryHolder<T>
{
    public int FamilyId { get; set; }
    public T CategoryData { get; set; }
}

public class StatusFilterData
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public bool HasOutcomes { get; set; }
}

public List<FollowUpsCategoryStatistics<StatusFilterData>> GetFollowUpIdsGroupedByFamily(int teamMemberId)
{

    Expression<Func<FollowUp, CategoryHolder<StatusFilterData>>> groupingKey = fup => 
        new CategoryHolder<StatusFilterData>()
        {
            FamilyId = fup.Family.Id,
            CategoryData = new StatusFilterData
            {
                Status = fup.Status.ToString(),
                HasOutcomes = fup.Campaign.FollowUpsOutcomes
                    .Any(outcome => outcome.ContactedMemberId == fup.Campaign.FollowUpsTeam.Id)
            }
        };

    //GetAssignedOpenFollowUps returns IQueryable<FollowUp> which from EF: DbSet<FollowUp>
    var doubleGroups = GetAssignedOpenFollowUps(teamMemberId)
        .GroupBy(groupingKey)
        .GroupBy(g => g.Key.CategoryData)
        .ToList();


    [...code removed for brevity]
}
```

This is fairly straight-forward. In order to get the correct groupings and associated counts etc., I have to group the data twice, first by using the FamilyId and the CategoryData, and a 2nd time by just the CategoryData. The first grouping will always use the FamnilyId but the CategoryData generic type which is used in both the 1st and 2nd groupings can change (in the above example it's the StatusFilterData object). The above works well and it correctly produces the result I'm after, but only for the scenario where the CategoryData is of type StatusFilterData.

What I'm attempting to do and failing, is to make the CategoryHolder.CategoryData dynamic by turning the function into a generic and passing in an Expression so that I can define the result in the calling code, thus:

```
private List<FollowUpsCategoryStatistics<FollowUpsServices.StatusFilterData>> GetStatusFilterData()
{
    var currentUser = new SessionHelper().GetCurrentUser();
    var result = _followUpsServices.GetFollowUpIdsGroupedByFamily(
        currentUser,
        fup => new FollowUpsServices.StatusFilterData
        {
            Status = fup.Status.ToString(),
            HasOutcomes = fup.Campaign.FollowUpsOutcomes
                .Any(outcome => outcome.ContactedMemberId == fup.Campaign.FollowUpsTeam.Id)
        }
    );

    return result;
}

public List<FollowUpsCategoryStatistics<TReturn>> GetFollowUpIdsGroupedByFamily<TReturn>(
    int teamMemberId,
    Expression<Func<FollowUp, TReturn>> categoryDataFunc
)
{

    Expression<Func<FollowUp, CategoryHolder<TReturn>>> groupingKey = fup => 
        new CategoryHolder<TReturn>()
        {
            FamilyId = fup.Family.Id,
            CategoryData = categoryDataFunc.Compile().Invoke(fup)
        };

    //GetAssignedOpenFollowUps returns IQueryable<FollowUp> which from EF: DbSet<FollowUp>
    var doubleGroups = GetAssignedOpenFollowUps(teamMemberId)
        .GroupBy(groupingKey)
        .GroupBy(g => g.Key.CategoryData)
        .ToList();

    [...code removed for brevity]
}
```

Although the compiler is ok with this, Linq to Entities isn't as the Func within the Func isn't supported - the `categoryDataFunc.Compile().Invoke(fup)` with the existing Expression is the problem.

I've tried looking up how to create an Expression tree, but quite frankly I'm struggling and have spent hours going nowhere fast as Expression Trees are new to me, and although there are several great examples around, I can't work out how to make any of them apply to my specific scenario.

If anyone has the knowledge and time to help I'd be grateful for the assist.

Cheers,

Paul

Comment: Why don't you just do that by returing an IQueryable or IEnumerable to the calling code and write the logic there?  You have the caller write the logic _anyway_.  What's the benefit of having the caller package the logic into an expression and push it into a library method?

Comment: Hi David. Thanks for your reply. Basically there's a lot of code AFTER the bits you've seen and due to a separate quirk of EF I'm obliged to call the .ToList() before all those extra bits (relates to the `FollowUpsCategoryStatistics` - so it means that if I were to return an IQueryable then the calling code would have to repeat all those extra bits each time, and of course I'm trying to create abstractions where possible, reduce code repetition and keep certain code within particular areas of responsibilities.

Comment: Still no need to pass `Expression<Func<...` around.  Extension methods on either `IQueryable<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>` are a much more natural (fluent) way to compose query logic.

Comment: Sure, it may be easier and more fluent, but I failed to mention that the query is in the middle-tier and the calling code is in the front-end. I should be defining as much as possible in the middle-tier to promote code reuse. One could maybe, kinda, possibly get away with the front-end 'knowing' all the necessary bits but it starts to get unwieldy as soon as you start connecting other clients such as an API in front of the middle-tier. I'm just not convinced it makes sense to return an IQueryable to the client, to then use an extension method back in the middle-tier because it's easier. :S

Comment: Why not?  It’s the obvious solution.

Comment: Hmmm... How about single areas of responsibility etc etc (SOLID), encapsulation, clarity of intent and purpose, testability... Simply returning IQueryable's willy nilly from the middle-tier is chaos. Call me old fashioned - perhaps I've been writing code for too long?

Comment: Sorry, not trying to troll you David. It's just that if returning an IQueryable from the middle-tier was what I wanted to do then I would have just done that. We're having more of a philosophical conversation than I wanted when really I was just looking for someone to point me in the direction of the answer I originally asked.

Comment: Can you simplify the scenario and provide a usable repro with entity definitions?